# Remove bias from the monthly totals

Tags: sql, select, group-by, sybase

In order to remove the bias introduced by the differences in the number of days in the months and years (in case of leap years), from monthly total comparisons of arbitrary quantities and assuming, for example, a table named `My_Table` with a datetime column named `order_date`, and an integer one named `revenue`, I use the following query to get unbiased monthly revenue totals:

```
-- sum revenue per month, divided by the number of days of that month 
-- and then multiplied by the average days of the that year's months 

SELECT datepart(mm,order_date) as my_month, sum(
round(convert(decimal, revenue) /
    CASE WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 2 THEN
CASE WHEN (YEAR(order_date) % 4 = 0 AND YEAR(order_date) % 100 != 0) OR 
          (YEAR(order_date) % 400  = 0) THEN 29 ELSE 28 END
     WHEN (MONTH(order_date)%8 + floor(MONTH(order_date)/8)) % 2 = 0 THEN 30 ELSE 31 END
    * CASE WHEN (YEAR(order_date) % 4 = 0 AND YEAR(order_date) % 100 != 0) OR 
                (YEAR(order_date) % 400  = 0) THEN 366 ELSE 365 END / 12 , 3)
) as monthly_unb_revenue 
FROM My_Table
group by datepart(mm,order_date)
```

I would like your opinions or other practices

Comment: Just curious, is this for a particular database system? Uniquely available functions might help.

Comment: yes, actually is a sybase query - I forgot to clarify that :)

Answer (score 1):

Rolling your own calendar calculations can be hard.  It's probably more reliable to use built-in functions.

For example, you can find the first day of any month like:

```
DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,DateColumn),0)
```

Doing a `datediff` between the two would get you the number of days for that month.  You could do the same for years:

```
select 
    datediff(d,
        DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate()),0),
        DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate())+1,0)) 
        as NumOfDaysThisMonth,
    datediff(d,
        DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()),0),
        DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate())+1,0)) 
        as NumOfDaysThisYear
```

This example works on SQL Server, hopefully there's an equivalent on Sybase :)

Comment: Thank you. It seems that in Sybase the syntax is slightly different, e.g. DATEDIFF requires a datepart and 2 date arguments. In expression DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate()), 0 is not accepted. Anyway i got your point !

Comment: In SQL server, the date `0` maps to `'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'`.  You could enter the date as a string in Sybase.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using SQL Server since that seems to be the only system I know of with datepart().

In oracle and MySQL you have a LAST_DAY() function.  I found a user defined function equivalent for SQL Server [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/get-last-day-of-month.aspx):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_GetLastDayOfMonth] ( @pInputDate    DATETIME )
RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN

    DECLARE @vOutputDate        DATETIME

    SET @vOutputDate = CAST(YEAR(@pInputDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' + 
                       CAST(MONTH(@pInputDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/01'
    SET @vOutputDate = DATEADD(DD, -1, DATEADD(M, 1, @vOutputDate))

    RETURN @vOutputDate

END 
GO
```

You could add that function and then use it to simplify your query.

Comment: In SQL Server you can find the last day of a month with `DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@InputDate)+1,0))`.  But it appears that the OP is using Sybase :)